# Asp.net Textbox.Autopostback causes another issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox, autopostback

I have dropdown and texboxes and one button on the form. I'm using 'autopostback=true' for all the form elements. When you fill the form you need to push 'send' button. But because of texbox.autopostback, you need to push 2 time to send form.

If you select dropdown lastly, then there is no problem. But if you're filling textboxes than you need to click 2 time to send form.

Is there any solution for it? I must use textboxes.autopostback='true' but need some solution.

Thanks,

UPDATE:

All controls stays in updatepanel element.

Comment: Are you sure you need autopostback? What are you doing in that postback?

Comment: i'm using validations to check controls. (dynamically) @Crowcoder

Comment: Many validations can be done client side in javascript, and then again server side when the form is submitted. If you can only use server side validation then your options are to have multiple postbacks or use ajax to do validations asynchronously.

Comment: I agree with @Crowcoder. Try to do all validations using javascript in clientside

Comment: It would help immensely if you showed the code.
Also, what behavior would you like? Why have you enabled autopostback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set a hidden field value to "1" when textbox posts back and its value is valid, else set the hidden field value to "0"
- On client-side, in pageLoad event, automatically click the button if the hidden field value is "1". So, to the user button is only clicked once and your auto submitting the form when text post back returns.

Both the above points need to be done in your code-behind.

The result of of this logic will enforce a consistent workflow, where the button can be clicked only once to submit the page.

Comment: seems nice but the main problem is like that: when you click and select dropdown and than submit button = no problem. When you're filling textbox than you need to click somewhere to autopostback for serverside validations. it cloud be empty background or other textboxes doesn't metter. Than send button works again. Or you just click 2 times to send button after filling textbox. I think we need some "onfocusout" event for textboxes or something like that? By the way, i forgot to tell, all controls are in updatepanel @Sunil

Comment: In that case you can write JavaScript in `pageLoad` client-side event. When textbox posts back, you can set a hidden field in code-behind in addition to the other logic I have mentioned in my answer. In pageLoad event, write JavaScript to get hidden field value; if this value is `"1"` then textbox posted back and use this code `if(hdnValue == "1") { btnPost.Click(); btn.disabled =  true;}`. This will only mean user clicks the button once when textbox is posts  back.